# UITableViewCell scrolling is janky when the scrolling is slow / decellarating

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have this problem where I have relatively sophisticated table view cell using autolayout, and I can't seem to understand why scrolling is jerky at slow speed.

I have run it through Instruments with Time Profiler but nothing really stands out as the major cause. Additionally, when I scroll really quickly, it goes smoothly on my iPhone 6s. I have verified that I can get to 55 - 60 FPS using Instruments with Core Animation. This issue only happens when I scroll a little bit.

Here are some facts which I think are relevant:

1. The table view is using automatic dimension using estimated row height.
2. Cells are being reused.
3. The table view has 20+ sections, and each section could have up to 3 rows.
4. Each cell has a collection view that displays photos in a grid format. The height of this collection view changes based on how many photos to show in the grid using height constraint.
5. I tried to eradicate all the blended layers, but that doesn't fix the issue I am seeing.
6. Even tried a simple solution of caching cell height in willDisplayCell delegate method and see if scrolling upwards will be smoother. That didn't work.

I am happy to provide more data points, but I am stuck in a way I don't know what else to try or look for.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the photo, are you getting it from a url?

Comment: Yes, photos are retrieved asynchronously via SDWebImage @BashirSidani

Comment: I have been looking at this more, and it turns out that there was a lot spike in CPU usage (in Time Profiler) that was hard to see without zooming in. I am still trying to make my scrolling smooth, but it seems to be creating and assigning attributed strings are expensive. I have pushed off creation to our cache layer but I don't know what I can do optimize assigning attributed strings to UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Hope You can find the answer in the bottom of the page in below link

[What is UITableView separatorEffect property for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090913/what-is-uitableview-separatoreffect-property-for)

Comment: I didn't know about that but I double check that I didn't have separatorEffect set to my table view. So I don't think this is the cause.